# OpenVPN: raspberry pi AP to other pi w/ VPN

Tags: raspberry-pi, openvpn, vpn, access-point

I've established, I hope, an `openvpn` server on my raspberry pi at my house. I have another Raspberry Pi acting as an AP at my university so that my lab can connect to the internet through the AP. I'm trying to get it so that all data are encrypted to the VPN at my house. I installed `openVPN` and created a client configuration file based on https://sys.jonaharagon.com/2016/05/12/connecting-to-your-pi-openvpn-server-part-2/ (and I created the server based on that site) and put it on my Pi at the university. I'm having trouble getting my  university Pi  to connect to the vpn server, but that's another story.

My question right now is, if I do get the connection established, considering the university Pi is acting as an AP, how do I know data are actually being encrypted to the Pi at my house? I know any data from stuff happening on my University pi will obviously be encrypted, but is it safe to assume all data coming in from other computers connected to it as the AP are also being encrypted?

Comment: Wireshark or such should show whether the traffic is encrypted or not...